# Most efficient way to store pandas Dataframe on disk for frequent access?

Tags: python, pandas, serialization

I am working on an application which generates a couple of hundred datasets every ten minutes. These datasets consist of a timestamp, and some corresponding values from an ongoing measurement.
(Almost) Naturally, I use pandas dataframes to manage the data in memory.

Now I need to do some work with history data (eg. averaging or summation over days/weeks/months etc. but not limited to that), and I need to update those accumulated values rather frequently (ideally also every ten minutes), so I am wondering which would be the most access-efficient way to store the data on disk?

So far I have been storing the data for every ten minute interval in a separate csv-file and then read the relevant files into a new dataframe as needed. But I feel that there must be a more efficient way, especially when it comes to working with a larger amount of datasets. Although computation cost and memory are not the central issue, as I am running the code on a comparatively powerful machine, but I still don't want to (and most likely, can't afford to) read all the data into memory every time.

It seems to me that the answer should lie within the built-in serialization functions of pandas, but from the docs and my google findings I honestly can't really tell which would fit my needs best.

Any ideas how I could manage my data better?

Comment: Seems like you want something more persistent, with built-in i/o data access. Like perhaps a postgresql server.

Comment: [Database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database)

Comment: I was afraid you would suggest that... 
Actually I had hoped for a solution directly in Python without having to setup anything else, but I'll take a look into your suggestions. Thanks!